# Can I make Recognizing digital ink works with numbers only?

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I have a panel to write numbers by the user and I want when the user removes his finger from the screen, the number drawn by the user will show in TextView.

I want to use [Recognizing digital ink with ML Kit on Android](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition/android), Checklist below :

- Draw 1 = Most cases return I or i letter
- Draw 4 = Most cases return u, U, y, or Y letter
- Draw 5 = Most cases return S or s letter

Can I make Recognizing digital ink works with numbers only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no numbers-only model shipped within ML Kit nor a way
to restrict the classes of characters (such as digits) considered during
the recognition phase.

What can help however, with using a regular language recognizer (such as
English), is to set a numeric "precontext"  label (e.g. "0123") in the
[RecognitionContext](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/digitalink/RecognitionContext#public-abstract-string-getprecontext) passed in the [recognize](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/digitalink/DigitalInkRecognizer#public-abstract-taskrecognitionresult-recognize-ink-ink,-recognitioncontext-context) call. This will bias the recognizer more towards recognizing digits.
Furthermore, you can set a high value (e.g. 100) for the maximum number of
returned results in the recognizer [options](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/digitalink/DigitalInkRecognizerOptions.Builder#public-abstract-digitalinkrecognizeroptions.builder-setmaxresultcount-int-resultcount).
You could then iterate through the [RecognitionCandidates](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/digitalink/RecognitionResult#public-listrecognitioncandidate-getcandidates) list (which is sorted starting with the most likely) and filter out
non-numeric results.

Comment: Late answer but thank you I'll check the URLs :)